# How to export SQLite to JSON?

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to get a SQLite view on a JSON file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to do this via a programming language (if so, which one)? Or, are you wanting to do this from the command line?  Or, are you wanting to do this via an application (if so, which application)?

Comment: Either the title or the body of your question need editing. They are asking two different things. Did you mean "How to import a JSON file into SQLite?" or did you mean "Is there a way to export an SQLite view as a JSON file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On recent versions of SQLite, this is built in. The following:

```
sqlite3> .mode json
sqlite3> .once out.json
sqlite3> SELECT * from foo;
```

writes the table `foo` to `out.json`.

Or, directly from the command line:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3 '.mode json' '.once out.json' 'select * from foo'
```

`.once`, which writes the output of the next SQL command to the indicated file, has been in SQLite since [3.8.5 in 2014](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_5).

The `.mode json` is newer though, added in [3.33.0 in 2020-08](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_33_0). It comes with ubuntu 20.10 but older operating systems are unlikely to have that feature in their built-in SQLite version.

Answer (score 5):

`SQLiteStudio` [(sqlitestudio.pl)](https://sqlitestudio.pl) can export from sqlite3 database to JSON. SQLiteStudio is C++ Qt-based, open source GPLv3 licensed, Linux/macOS/Windows application with a git repository here: '[pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio)'.

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly ways to do this.  For example, you could write a custom program that parses the JSON input via your favorite JSON processor and then generate the equivalent SQL statements to create tables, insert the rows, etc. and then import that into a [SQLite capable tool (DB Browser for SQLite)](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to generate the actual SQLite db file.

I suspect you will be hard pressed to find a general purpose tool to accomplish this, as the content of the JSON input could vary widely, and in fact may not map well into a relational database at all.

Comment: I was looking for a way to visualize data from a SQLite database in a Protovis chart. I guess it won't be easy...