# Convert SQLite to MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, sqlite, database-migration

I have a normalized SQLite database and I want to convert to one collection MongoDB database.
let's take an example:

We suppose that my SQLite database looks like :
[SQLite database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwzTB.png)

I want my MongoDB database looks like :

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5efdf2c2b268674c2bf74e85"),
   "firstName": "robert",
   "lastName": "kas", 
   "addresses":[
               {
               "address": "This is address 1",
               "type": "home",
               },
               {
               "address": "This is address 2",
               "type": "work",
               }
              ]
}
```

Comment: Any preference which tool you like to use?

Comment: using tools in what?

Comment: Which tool (or programming language) you like to use to make the migration?

Comment: currently, I'm learning node.js, but I feel more comfortable with java

Comment: Then do it in Java. Look how to select data from SQLite, read it row by row and write it to Mongo. I don't think there is any tool where your could do it with a single command.

Comment: When you have code samples, highlight the text and click {} in the toolbar, or put 4 spaces in front of each line. That way it will show up in preforrmatted text.

Comment: You can try one of the options in the following post to get JSON from the sqlite database tables. Then you can import the JSON into MongoDB and build your collection: [Convert SQLite to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722585/convert-sqlite-to-json).