# Impossible to export SQLite query results to JSON?

Tags: json, sqlite

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67186486/15021571) and tried this:

```
sqlite3 peds.db '.mode json' '.once out.json' 'select startn, rel, endn, desc, priority, finding, explanation from dx_graph FOR JSON AUTO'
```

but it said:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "sqlite3": syntax error
At line 1:
sqlite3
```

It seems to me like this is not possible anymore? I was unable to find any more recent answers.

BTW I am using this code in the "execute SQL" tab of my SQLite DB Browser.

Comment: This command should be executed in the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working

Comment: You can export to json in SQLite DB Browser from File->Export->Table(s) to json

Comment: Thank you, but that does not answer my question because I am looking to export a specific query.

Comment: Create a view with your query: `CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT ....`. It can be exported too.

Comment: Wow that also works!! Very cool. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me (inserted into the terminal)

```
sqlite3 -json '/Users/anon/DxHero Godot/Data/peds.db' 'select startn, rel, endn, desc, priority, finding, explanation from dx_graph' >  '/Users/gtye/DxHero Godot/Data/dx_graph.json'
```

For more generalizable answer:

```
sqlite3 -json '<db file path>' '<sqlite query>' > '<output file path>'
```