# Can't export sqlite to json because the json option disappeared?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, export

I'm trying to export specific columns of my sqlite database into json.

I found a question relevant to my issue here: [Impossible to export SQLite query results to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762109/impossible-to-export-sqlite-query-results-to-json)

Where they used the sqlite3 `-json` option to solve their problem and export their sqlite database to json.

However, when I try to do the same terminal command I get this in return:

`sqlite3: Error: unknown option: -json`

and `sqlite3 -help` returns the following list of options:

```
-append              append the database to the end of the file
   -ascii               set output mode to 'ascii'
   -bail                stop after hitting an error
   -batch               force batch I/O
   -column              set output mode to 'column'
   -cmd COMMAND         run "COMMAND" before reading stdin
   -csv                 set output mode to 'csv'
   -deserialize         open the database using sqlite3_deserialize()
   -echo                print commands before execution
   -init FILENAME       read/process named file
   -[no]header          turn headers on or off
   -help                show this message
   -html                set output mode to HTML
   -interactive         force interactive I/O
   -line                set output mode to 'line'
   -list                set output mode to 'list'
   -lookaside SIZE N    use N entries of SZ bytes for lookaside memory
   -maxsize N           maximum size for a --deserialize database
   -memtrace            trace all memory allocations and deallocations
   -newline SEP         set output row separator. Default: '\n'
   -nullvalue TEXT      set text string for NULL values. Default ''
   -pagecache SIZE N    use N slots of SZ bytes each for page cache memory
   -quote               set output mode to 'quote'
   -readonly            open the database read-only
   -separator SEP       set output column separator. Default: '|'
   -stats               print memory stats before each finalize
   -version             show SQLite version
   -vfs NAME            use NAME as the default VFS
```

`json` is nowhere to be found. Very strange, because the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/cli.html#command_line_options) shows the following:

```
$ sqlite3 --help
Usage: ./sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
FILENAME is the name of an SQLite database. A new database is created
if the file does not previously exist.
OPTIONS include:
   -A ARGS...           run ".archive ARGS" and exit
   -append              append the database to the end of the file
   -ascii               set output mode to 'ascii'
   -bail                stop after hitting an error
   -batch               force batch I/O
   -box                 set output mode to 'box'
   -column              set output mode to 'column'
   -cmd COMMAND         run "COMMAND" before reading stdin
   -csv                 set output mode to 'csv'
   -deserialize         open the database using sqlite3_deserialize()
   -echo                print commands before execution
   -init FILENAME       read/process named file
   -[no]header          turn headers on or off
   -help                show this message
   -html                set output mode to HTML
   -interactive         force interactive I/O
   -json                set output mode to 'json'
   -line                set output mode to 'line'
   -list                set output mode to 'list'
   -lookaside SIZE N    use N entries of SZ bytes for lookaside memory
   -markdown            set output mode to 'markdown'
   -maxsize N           maximum size for a --deserialize database
   -memtrace            trace all memory allocations and deallocations
   -mmap N              default mmap size set to N
   -newline SEP         set output row separator. Default: '\n'
   -nofollow            refuse to open symbolic links to database files
   -nonce STRING        set the safe-mode escape nonce
   -nullvalue TEXT      set text string for NULL values. Default ''
   -pagecache SIZE N    use N slots of SZ bytes each for page cache memory
   -quote               set output mode to 'quote'
   -readonly            open the database read-only
   -safe                enable safe-mode
   -separator SEP       set output column separator. Default: '|'
   -stats               print memory stats before each finalize
   -table               set output mode to 'table'
   -tabs                set output mode to 'tabs'
   -version             show SQLite version
   -vfs NAME            use NAME as the default VFS
   -zip                 open the file as a ZIP Archive
```

As you can see, `-json` is clearly listed as an option (as well as many others that don't show up for me).

What's going on?

Comment: check your version (`sqlite3 -version`). json was added as an output mode in [release 3.33.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_33_0.html)

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head! I had version 3.28.0 and just upgraded to version 3.37.2. Unfortunately, now I'm having another problem. `sqlite3 --version` still returns 3.28.0, but when I `brew upgrade sqlite3` I get this result: `Warning: sqlite3 3.37.2 already installed`

Comment: Was able to solve it by inputting `/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3` into the terminal instead of just `sqlite3`. Doesn't seem like an optimal solution, though.